# Haskell - Exposing IO actions in API

Tags: api, haskell, monads

I wrote a small library[[1](https://github.com/lwm/spanish-conjugator)] that interfaces with a postgresql DB which contains 600+ Spanish verbs and pulls out conjugations and other useful things.

I have a single function which performs the DB read. It looks like this (I am using the postgresql-simple[[2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple)] library):

```
-- | A postgres query.
queryDB              :: (ToRow params, FromRow a) => Query -> params -> IO [a]
queryDB q paramTypes =  do
    c      <-  connection
    return =<< query c q paramTypes
```

Each function that I expose in the library, uses this function and returns an IO action of some type. For example, if the user conjugates the verb 'ser' using `conjugate`, I get back a `IO [Conjugation]`:

```
-- | Conjugate the verb 'i' in the tense 't' and mood 'm'.
-- 
-- > conjugate "ser" "Presente" "Indicativo"
conjugate       :: Infinitive -> Tense -> Mood -> IO [Conjugation]
conjugate i t m =  queryDB conjugationQuery [i :: Infinitive, 
                                             t :: Tense, 
                                             m :: Mood]
```

I am new to writing libraries in Haskell. Is it fine to leave functions such as `conjugate` to export IO actions? They do interact with the DB, but that isn't really the point of the function ... the user just wants conjugations. Normally, if I would write code like this in another language, the user would not know an IO action has taken place.

Can I seperate IO and expose pure functions?

Comment: `c      <-  connection` - this part terrifies me, considering that it's done in `IO`. I suspect you're using `unsafePerformIO` somewhere for this, right? This is a code smell per se. Consider learning `ReaderT` instead.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Huh? This is in IO, so `c` is pulling the current connection out of some global or whatever. The type is `IO [a]`, so unsafePerformIO is obviously not necessary.

Comment: `connection :: IO Connection; connection = do {config <- readConfigFile; doConnectToDB config}`? There are like a million plausible implementations, and none of them need unsafePerformIO, because the type is `IO Connection`, not `Connection`.

Comment: @amalloy And how would you declare this "global" if not with `unsafePreformIO`? Besides, this is exactly what I'm talking about, a global variable is the code smell. It only makes sense in some very special cases of hacking with Haskell's RTS.

Comment: @amalloy `connection = do {config <- readConfigFile; doConnectToDB config}` - so, reestablish a connection on every query? Are you freakin serious?

Comment: So look it up in a cache, whatever. The point is it doesn't need unsafePerformIO because it's in IO explicitly. I'm objecting to your absurd conclusion that `c <- connection` implies unsafePerformIO, where to me it implies *lack* of unsafePerformIO (compared to, say, `c = connection`). The details of how this is implemented, or whether a global `connection` is good design, I'm not interested in arguing about.

Comment: @amalloy "So look it up in a cache, whatever." - No it's not whatever. My point is that there would be no other way to declare such a cache but using `unsafePerformIO`. "absurd conclusion" - Okay, present me a single example, which does not use `unsafePerformIO` and is not ridiculous like your previous one. Otherwise I suggest you apologise.

Comment: No, thanks. I don't think this discussion is enriching the lives of either of us, or of anyone else reading the comments.

Comment: Damn, I thought all these notifications were for useful informative answers ...

Comment: @decentralised The conversation above points out that you either create a bottleneck due to a terrible misuse of resources or implement an antipattern. Of course it's up to you to consider whether an information like that is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're hitting a database, no.  A huge part of Haskell is specifying to someone using your API that they're performing an IO action.  Since IO actions can fail, return different results for the same input, or fire the missiles, we always tell the user when this happens.

What would happen if I used your API but didn't have your database as well?  Then I would likely see some sort of error message about not having a connection.  Or if I did have your database but modified it to return incorrect conjugations, then you can't guarantee that `conjugate` will always return the same conjugations given a particular infinitive, tense, and mood.  This means that you can't have your `conjugate` function be pure.

Comment: Well... If the database can be made a data structure that's passed around, the code that loads it can be separated from the code that uses it.

Comment: @Carl Yes, the code that uses the values returned from a database query can be pure, but the function that pulls the data structure from the database can not be made pure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid reconnecting to the database for every query, one thing you can do is make a `newtype` wrapper over `ReaderT Connection IO` that you use all over the place, and then provide a separate `runDB` function:

```
newtype DB a = MkDB{ unDB :: ReaderT DBConnection IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

queryDB  :: (ToRow params, FromRow a) => Query -> params -> DB [a]
queryDB q paramTypes =  MkDB $ do
    c <- ask
    lift $ query c q paramTypes

conjugate :: Infinitive -> Tense -> Mood -> DB [Conjugation]
conjugate i t m =  queryDB conjugationQuery [i :: Infinitive, 
                                             t :: Tense, 
                                             m :: Mood]

-- Of course, this still needs to be in IO
runDB :: DB a -> IO a
runDB db = runReaderT db =<< connection
```

The crucial bit is to **not** export `MkDB` and `unDB`; `DB` is an opaque type that the user can only use via the exported functions (`conjugate` etc.) and the monadic combinators. This way, undiluted IO is not spread all over the client code.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this strategy. If this is completely new territory for anyone else (like me!), these two links helped me grok the idea. [All about Monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads) and [Monad Transformers step by step](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf)